# Fatal Error while fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysqli

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\cronjob\SQLreader.php on line 13

```
<?php
//readout Top10
// Hier mySQL - Zugangsdaten eingeben.
$servername = "*";
$username = "*";
$password = "*";
$db = "*";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

$user = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM btcstats ORDER BY kdr DESC LIMIT 10");

while($a = $user->fetch_assoc()) {
    $file = fopen("statscache.txt", "w+");
    fwrite($file, $a['uuid'] . "|" . $a['kills'] . "|" . $a['deaths'] . "|" . $a['gamesplayed'] . $a['gameswon'] . "|/n");
    fclose($file);
}
```

So we've got a problem here, can some find the mistake ?

Comment: your query failed and you need to find out why that is http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: one reason may be here `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);` change this to `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $db,  $username, $password);`

Comment: @Shehary no, DB comes last.

Comment: @Fred-ii- still trying to hold my grip on this MySQLi :(

Comment: oh btw, the syntax is `\n` and not `/n`.

Comment: It make no sense that the database will be definied before the password so there is connection at this time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer is in the [mysqli::query documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Clearly there is a MySQL error occurring, and the function is returning 'false'.

```
$user = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM btcstats ORDER BY kdr DESC LIMIT 10");

if ($user) {
    while($a = $user->fetch_assoc()) {
        $file = fopen("statscache.txt", "w+");
        fwrite($file, $a['uuid'] . "|" . $a['kills'] . "|" . $a['deaths'] . "|" . $a['gamesplayed'] . $a['gameswon'] . "|/n");
        fclose($file);
    }
} else {
    die ("Mysql error: " . $conn->error);
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: You might want to have a second look at `/n`.

Comment: Yeah, he should probably fix that, too, but that's not the part that's throwing his error.

Comment: Not my downvote @samlev no idea why. Maybe the dv'er cares to explain?

Comment: Your query looks the same as the original. What is the fix? Skipping the `while` loop is not a real solution, you need to fix the problem in the query.

Comment: I'm not going to try to debug his query. I'm guessing a column error or something. By actually seeing the error, he can find and fix the problem himself.